# Filter Data with Spring JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have got Persons and I just want to get the ones starting with a certain letter (the letter is from an input field). I have got the query but I can't 'use' it.
And how can I make this possible?

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer>{

    @Query("From Person where firstname like CONCAT(:firstname,'%')")
    Stream<Person> findAllWithSearchParams(@Param("firstname") String firstname);


}
```

Service:

```
@Service 
public class PersonService { 

   @Autowired 
   private PersonRepository personRepository;         
   public Stream<Person> all(Person mysearch){ 
       return personRepository 
              .findAll(Example.of(mysearch)) 
              .stream() 
              .map(Person::fromPerson); 
  } 
}
```

Class Person:

```
public class Person { 

    public Integer index; 
    public String firstname; 
    public String lastname; 
    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy") 
    public Date exdate; 
    public String insnr; 

    private Person(Integer index, String firstname, String lastname, Date exdate, String insnr){ 
        this.index=index; 
        this.firstname=firstname; 
        this.lastname=lastname; 
        this.exdate=exdate; 
        this.insnr=insnr; 
    } 

    public static Person fromPerson(Person person){ 
        return person == null ? null : new Person(person.getIndex(), person.getFirstname(), person.getLastname(), person.getExdate(), person.getInsnr()); 
    } 
}
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired 
   private PersonService personService; 
   @RequestMapping(value="/person/list/**") 
   public List<Person> loadPersonList(   
                   @RequestParam(value = "firstname" ,required=false) String firstname) throws ParseException {         
       mysearch.setFirstname(firstname); 
       return personService.all(mysearch).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
   }
```

Comment: what do u meant by you cant use it

Comment: I'm getting the error 'The method stream() is undefined for the type Stream<Person>'.

Comment: I found my mistake, should have thought a little bit more. Had to change the Stream to List @Query("From Person where firstname like CONCAT(:firstname,'%')")
    **Stream**<Person> findAllWithSearchParams(@Param("firstname") String firstname);

Comment: Is this: `findByFirstnameStartingWith(String firstname)`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want a query that find person starting with a certain letter or word. So, you just need:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {

    List<Person> findByFirstnameStartingWith(String firstname);

}
```